Matrix of reflection along a line with respect to a basis
The equation of a plane ( U ) in a three-dimensional linear space is
$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0
$
with respect to some basis. Find the matrix with respect to that basis of reflection in ( U ) along the line
$
x = t(0, 1, 1).
$
I have tried geting the matrix of the projection by creating a general point belonging to the line and then replacing it on the equation of the plane. And with the projection matrix then calculate reflection matrix according to:
$R=I-2P$
However this did not seem to work. Any advice is appreciated!

The terminology of "reflection" in a line (rather than in a plane) seems to be a source of confusion here.  My guess is that you want a rotation around the line (taken as an axis) rather than a reflection per se.

I think what the OP wants is the reflection of the line in the plane. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Since the normal to the plane $U$ is $(1,1,1)$, for any point $(x,y,z)$, the projection onto the plane is given by $(x,y,z)-s(1,1,1)$ for some $s\in \mathbb R$ such that $(x-s)+(y-s)+(z-s)=0$. The reflected point is given by $(x,y,z)-2s(1,1,1)$, where $s$ is found in the last sentence. Given this linear transformation, it is not too hard to construct the corresponding matrix.

where does the line come into play though?

Once you have the linear transformation on all points, you can apply it on the points on the line. That should give you the points on the reflected line. (I’m assuming that’s what you wanted to compute in your question.)
